# TypeScript type definitions: how to declare class constructors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a home-brew JavaScript library (one js file) that contains a number of classes. In order to use it in my TypeScript projects, I have created a d.ts file that contains type definitions for all those classes. A typical definition would look like this:

```
export interface ClassExample {
  new(param: boolean): ClassExample;
  propertyName: number|string;
  log(...args: any[]): void;
}
```

And it works well. But I am getting bashed by linter rule `@typescript-eslint/no-misused-new`: "Interfaces cannot be constructed, only classes". Of course, I can configure my linter and/or add exceptions for the particular `d.ts` file, but this makes me contemplate if there should be some other approach to describe my classes. Should an `abstract class` declaration be used instead? I tried to look up how the class constructors are declared for publicly available Node.js modules, and found this code in `@types/node/console.d.ts` file:

```
interface ConsoleConstructor {
  prototype: Console;
  new(stdout: WritableStream, stderr?: WritableStream, ignoreErrors?: boolean): Console;
  new(options: ConsoleConstructorOptions): Console;
}
```

So, I figure, declaring class constructors in interface is not a grave sin, if the authors of Node.js are practicing it?

Answer (score 6):

According to [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#classes), you'd declare that class with the `declare` keyword, like this:

```typescript
declare class ClassExample {
    constructor(param: boolean);
    propertyName: number|string;
    log(...args: any[]): void;
}
```

Here's the section linked above as it appears as of when this answer was written *(my emphasis)*:

> **Classes**
>
> *Documentation*
>
> You can create a `greeter` by instantiating the `Greeter` object, or create a customized `greeter` by extending from it.
>
> *Code*
>
> ```typescript
> const myGreeter = new Greeter("hello, world");
> myGreeter.greeting = "howdy";
> myGreeter.showGreeting();
>
> class SpecialGreeter extends Greeter {
>   constructor() {
>     super("Very special greetings");
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> *Declaration*
>
> **Use `declare class` to describe a `class` or `class`-like object.** Classes can have properties and methods as well as a `constructor`.
>
> ```typescript
> declare class Greeter {
>   constructor(greeting: string);
>
>   greeting: string;
>   showGreeting(): void;
> }
> ```